# Rails- Using check box to update database without submit button

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am new to rails and I am working on a online shopping project. I want to use a checkbox in the shopping-cart to let user to select whether to buy the product. But I don't like a submit button beside the checkbox. I know I have to use ajax to update the database without the submit button. But I did not make that work. Following is my code.

Here is jquery ajax,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".checkbox_submit").change(function(){
        $.ajax({url: {:action => create}, success: function(result){
            $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
        }});
    });
});
```

And this is my view, the first **td** is the checkbox

```
<tr>
    <td style="width: 5%;">
        <%= form_for cart_item, url: cart_item_path(cart_item.product_id), remote: true do |f| %>
            <%= f.check_box(:buy_now, class: "checkbox_submit") %>
        <% end %>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 20%;" >
        <%= link_to(product_path(cart_item.product)) do %><%= image_tag(cart_item.product.image.thumb.url) %><% end %>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 30%;"><%= link_to(cart_item.product.title, product_path(cart_item.product)) %></td>
    <td><%= cart_item.product.price %></td>
    <td>
        <%= form_for cart_item, url: cart_item_path(cart_item.product_id, remote: true) do |f| %>
            <%= f.select :quantity, 1..cart_item.product.storage, class: "select_submit" %>
        <% end %>
    </td>
    <td><strong>￥<%= cart_item.product.price * cart_item.quantity %></strong></td>
    <td><%= link_to(cart_item_path(cart_item.product_id), method: :delete) do %><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><% end %></td>
</tr>
```

And this is my controller

```
def update
        @cart = current_cart
        @cart_item = @cart.cart_items.find_by(product_id: params[:id])
        if @cart_item.product.storage >= cart_item_params[:quantity].to_i
            @cart_item.update(cart_item_params)
            redirect_to carts_path
        else
            redirect_to carts_path, alert: "exceed the storage"
        end

end
```

Could anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: When I click on the checkbox, nothing happens to the database.

Comment: what is the js error? is the request passing to controller ?

Comment: @jith the request did not pass to the controller

Comment: there must be some js error showing in web console.

Comment: @jith Do you mean this? `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`, I open the web console and find this.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

In js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".checkbox_submit").change(function(){
        var src = $(this);
        $.ajax({
          type: "post",
          url: "/sava_data", 
          success: function(result){
            src.parents('form:first').submit();
        }});
    });
});
```

In config/routes.rb

```
post '/save_data' => 'controller_name#action'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is better than my original one, but still got an error. `POST http://localhost:3000/save_data 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Do you mean this? `send @ jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:10255
ajax @ jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:9739(anonymous) @ cart_change.self-e3000ed….js?body=1:15
dispatch @ jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:5227
elemData.handle @ jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:4879
`

Comment: 1. Error logs displayed at your terminal.
2. Right click -> Inspect element -> console -> Error logs in red color.